# Weblogic config error - Message body writer for Java class, and Java type class, and MIME media type application/json was not found

Tags: java, json, configuration, jersey, weblogic

I'm running into an issue with my application running on a Weblogic server.  The weird part is that the application is fine on 3 other JVMs (6 managed servers).  There is one JVM with 2 managed servers that are both giving this error:

```
####<Oct 31, 2014 3:58:43 PM EDT> <Notice> <StdErr> <physaddress> <managedServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1414
785523072> <BEA-000000> <Oct 31, 2014 3:58:43 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General>
####<Oct 31, 2014 3:58:43 PM EDT> <Notice> <StdErr> <physaddress> <managedServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1414785523072> <BEA-000000> <Oct 31, 2014 3:58:43 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class xVO, and Java type class xVO, and MIME media type application/json was not found
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3741)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3705)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2282)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2181)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class xVO, and Java type class xVO, and MIME media type application/json was not found
        ... 21 more>
```

I'm not sure what other info could be helpful.  The server was working fine.  The thought is that there was some sort of config change that threw things off, but I'm unsure what it was.  Again, the application is running fine on 3 other instances of weblogic.  This particular instance is not working and we are unsure why.

Any assistance would be appreciated.
I would be happy to supply more info upon request.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you do a diff between the parameters of the servers that work and the ones that do not? Are the two managed servers new or have they always been there?

Comment: They have always been there.  Which parameters are you referring to.  I have checked the different managed servers on the Admin console and they seem to be configured the same there.  I've also checked the modules directory for Weblogic on both servers and they are identical.  At first I thought it could be that there was a newer version of one of the jars in there missing since we did add a few.  Thoughts?

Comment: I have seen this before so i thought it could be the case. If you use startup parameters and they are different, that could be the main cause. Different versions of WAR files can also cause it. Also check the commonEnv.sh and SetDomain.sh and make sure they are the same.

Comment: setDomainEnv.sh files are identical unfortunately. The wars are most definitely the same as they are deployed via the same upload to each server.

Comment: And you did not delete the cache, temp, stage and data and restart the managed servers?

Comment: We delete servers/[mgd_server_name]/tmp every time we restart.  I'm unfamiliar with the other 3 and their overall purpose.  Are they safe to delete?  Does EVERYTHING (less logs) under servers/[mgd_server_name]/ get recreated?  Seems like we have some ldap config under data so I'm not sure that should get deleted.

Comment: Its always safe to delete the whole folder under servers/[managed-server]/* . The security folder is not re-created which hosts your weblogic password but all the other folders get recreated. To be safe(if you want) you could just backup the data and security folder in a temp location and delete it.

Comment: I think that may have done it.  Initial tests seem to be working.  I will report back after more testing is completed, but as of right now, it's looking ok.  One thing I noticed is that in the stage directory, there were multiple directories for the same war (different versions).  On the working servers, there was only the most recent one.  I hope this works.  Again, I'll report back next week.  If you put this info as an answer, I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weblogic on very rare instances retains the old deployed file(of course it also depends on how the file was deployed) in the staging directory. Generally if there are inssues related to one weblogic server and not the other, stop the managed servers, deleting the tmp, stage or just moving it to a new directory and restarting the managed server makes the managed server pull the latest file and unzips it(stage keeps the war/ear file and tmp has the unzipped version). That most often fixes the issue.